# Access lookup Site column from subsite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, site, site-column, sub-site

Is it possible to create a lookup site column at root site and access it from its subsite? I created it using site column template at root site and it was accessible at root site when added it to a list in subsite, it was not populating any data. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to use it in a sub-site trhough a content type defined at the root level?

Comment: Tried it myself did not work

Answer (score 1):

If it's posible. Here are the steps:

1. Create a list in the root site.
2. Create a site column (of type lookup) in the root site referencing the list created in step 1.
3. In the sub site, in a list, create a column using the "Add from existing site columns"

And ready.

Learn more in this article: [Create a SharePoint Lookup Column to Another Site](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/04/17/create-a-sharepoint-lookup-column-to-another-site-aspx/)

Comment: This is exactly what i have done and it was not working !

Comment: You have verified permissions? Could you please paste a picture of the problem?

Comment: Its not a permission issue. I inherited the permission to the subsite.

Comment: I do not understand the phrase "After adding it to a list it will not populate it subsite root site column list items". The combobox in and subsite appears empty?

Comment: Yes, the look up column in the subsite is empty.

Comment: Very strange. No achievement realize what may be the problem. It occurs to me to review some sort of permissions to exclusive level in the list of root site. Try a user who is a site collection administrator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27418/discussion-between-sooraj-and-jpussacq).

Comment: @jpussacq I have tried what you suggest ('Try a user who is a site collection administrator') but the result was the same, have you been able to find a solution?