# How to link a list from a sub-site to a list in the Parent Site (or to a webpart on the sub-site)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible, without writing code, using SharePoint Designer 2013 to link a list from a sub-site to a list on the parent site?  I tried creating a webpart from the list on the parent site and placed on the sub-site but I cannot find a way to link to that view from the sub-site.  I was hoping by having the webpart from the parent site on the sub-site with the data that I would be able to link to that webpart thus allowing me to link to the data in the parent site.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more info? Du have List A in parent and List B in child? Are you trying to link with a lookup field?

Comment: Yes, List A is in the parent site and contains a column of information I want to select and store in list B in a sub-site.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

1. Create a list A in the root site.
2. Create a site column (of type
   lookup) in the root site referencing the list created in step 1.
3. In the sub site, in a list B, create a column using the "Add from existing site columns"

And ready.

More info here: [Access lookup Site column from subsite](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154135/access-lookup-site-column-from-subsite)